# Easy way to generate a pdf from a html form (IE compatible)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to generate a pdf from a simple html from with 12 inputfields.
I have tried to do this with jsPDF. All works fine but not with the IE.

Are there any easy plugin, which also works with IE? I prefer a Client-based Solution with Js & Html. I also want to draw lines in the pdf.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html2pdf.fr/en
this may be useful. i prefer using this; inline style css may be helpful to draw lines